# Search across file System -UWP (broad File System Access)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, winrt-xaml

Recently i learnt about broad file system access for the UWP apps, is there any API for searching the files for the given file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StorageFile` API offers `StorageFileQuery` API, which has this functionality built-in:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> SearchForFileAsync(StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
{            
    QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();
    options.ApplicationSearchFilter = "myfile.txt";
    options.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
    var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);                        
    return await query.GetFilesAsync(); 
}
```

The `ApplicationSearchFilter` proeprty supports Advanced Query Syntax (AQS), so you can include even placeholders like `*` and `?` in the search filter.

Finally to retrieve a folder on any particular path in the filesystem use the `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` method.

Comment: But  the access is only to the "using Windows.Storage;" namespace right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I haven't tested it and it really seems this limitation is present. I have updated my answer :-)

Comment: And with yet another update I found an API that does all the work for you :-)

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Have you solve your question by Martin Zikmund's solution?

Comment: Yes Xavier, still it’s not 100% sometimes the search api takes long time without giving any results, when I search from root directory

Comment: That is unfortunately a disadvantage. You could show a progress ring or manually walk through a few levels of folders and run this API from deeper folders only to have at least a partial awareness of how search is progressing.